# sums over one million display oddly with xquery

Tags: lucene, xquery

In the following xquery everything works as expected except that in the line below that reads:

```
<h2>Total word count: {format-number($sum, "0")}</h2>
```

If the sum is over a million it displays as:

"1.516908E6"

I don't understand this number. For example, why is there an "E"?

Anything below a million prints as expected, for example:

"72188" for 72,188.

I'm probably missing something basic, but I would be grateful for any help.

begin xquery

```
xquery version "3.0";

declare namespace tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0";

declare option exist:serialize "method=html media-type=text/html ident=no";

let $commentaryid := request:get-parameter('commentaryid', '')
let $collection := concat("scta", "/", $commentaryid)
let $terms := 
    <terms>
        {
            util:index-keys(
                collection(concat("/db/apps/", $collection))//tei:p, 
                "",
                function($key, $count) {
                    <term name="{$key}" count="{$count[1]}"
                        docs="{$count[2]}"/>
                }, -1, "lucene-index")
        }
    </terms>

let $sum := sum($terms//@count)
return 
    <html>
        <head>

        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Frequency analysis for {$collection}</h1> 
                <h2>Total word count: {format-number($sum, "0")}</h2>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Term</td>
                    <td>Frequency</td>
                    <td>Percentage</td>
                </tr>
                {
                    for $term in $terms//term

                        let $frequency := xs: integer($term/@count/string())
                        let $percentage := format-number(($term/@count div $sum), "%.00")
                        order by $frequency descending
                        return

                            <tr>
                                <td>{$term/@name/string()}</td>
                                <td>{$frequency}</td>
                                <td>{$percentage}%</td>
                            </tr>
                }
                </table>
                </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: Just to confirm, I assume from your use of `util:index-keys()` that your XQuery implementation is eXist. What version of eXist are you using?

Comment: Hi @joewiz, I'm running 3.0.RC1

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation

Comment: Ok, I think my answer is here: http://blog.msbbc.co.uk/2010/08/marklogic-xquery-safely-converting.html

Comment: Good. I think I used something similar when dealing with twitter post IDs; eXist was presenting the JSON form of these IDs in this form, and I used the `xs:decimal(xs:double("1.000000888E6"))` approach described on Alex Bleasdale's blog that you linked to as a workaround. Annoying to have to do so, but it works!

Comment: See Jens Erat's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36337725/scientific-notation-to-whole-numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath rules for converting xs:double to string say that numbers less than one-millionth or more than one million should be formatted in "scientific notation". If this isn't what you want, then it's probably best to convert the numbers to integers or decimals - preferably as early as possible. In your case the conversion to `xs:double` is happening implicitly where you write

```
sum($terms//@count)
```

and you could avoid it by using

```
sum($terms//xs:integer(@count))
```

**Postscript**

I don't think I read your question carefully enough. I didn't see that you were actually calling format-number() to output the value. format-number should never produce output in exponential/scientific notation unless you explicitly ask for it. So there is something else going on here, which might be specific to eXist.