# Scientific notation to whole numbers

Tags: xml, xquery

I'm extrapolating population growths 10 years in the future using some math functions in XQuery, like so:

```
let $db := doc("mondial.xml")

for $country in $db/mondial/country
  let $last_pop := $country/population[last()]
  let $snd_last_pop := $country/population[last() - 1]
  let $pop_growth := $last_pop div $snd_last_pop
  let $yt2026 := 2026 - $last_pop/@year

  return <country>
    {$country/name}
    <population year="2026" measured="extrap.">{
      $last_pop * math:exp($yt2026 * math:log($pop_growth))
    }</population>
  </country>
```

However, my output is either in scientific notation, or has a lot of decimal places.

```
<country>
  <name>Albania</name>
  <population year="2026" measured="extrap.">706860.8616776819</population>
</country>
<country>
  <name>Greece</name>
  <population year="2026" measured="extrap.">9.19404785580711E6</population>
</country>
<country>
  <name>Macedonia</name>
[...]
```

Using `xs:int()` produces an error.

How do I show these values in whole numbers?
(And what is the name of this notation? 'Normal notation'?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enforce non-scientific output without fractional digits using `format-number(9.19404785580711E6, "0")`. The value is rounded before being returned, such that the result for the given statement would be `9194048`.

Comment: Thanks, works well enough. You wouldn't happen to know how to insert commas, so that 760389 becomes 760,389?

Comment: `format-number(9.19404785580711E6, ",##0")` returns `9,194,048` -- `0` denotes  _required_ positions (`000` for the number 42 will return `042`),  you can use `#` to denote "fill up" positions and add the thousands separator as required.